# How to link CSS file to pdf.html file for Django, fixing a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, html, css, django

My PDF.html is not linking to any CSS file, I have tried the following:

Template PDF.HTML

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href='{% static "css/mdb.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
<link href='{% static "css/style.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using the same CSS files for other templates as base.html which is working fine and linking to them but for this particular HTML it is not linking, so I am trying to find the reason for this issue

Here is the base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
-----------------------------------------------------

<link href='{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href='{% static "css/mdb.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
<link href='{% static "css/style.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using weazyprint to get the pdf so here is the views I have tried to use it but it is returned `FileNotFoundError at /admin/order/50/pdf/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\static_rootcss/pdf.css'`

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order,ordered=True, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename="order_{order.id}.pdf"'    
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, 
                    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

I am using the followig config in the settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Did you extend `base.html` in `pdf.html`?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I am not trying to extend it to the Base.html and I am trying to link it to CSS file only. As a test to I actually extended it to Base and it worked showed nav bars and other things but this is a pdf file so I am trying to add only CSS to this html

Comment: Can you try reloading the page by clicking: `ctrl+F5` to check if it is a cache problm.

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane i did it several times no effect

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I added some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, 
                    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/css/pdf.css')])
```

#### EDIT

It seems like `settings.STATIC_ROOT` was not pointing towards the correct path. So, adding the correct path i.e `STATICFILES_DIRS` will work. So:

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order,ordered=True, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename="order_{order.id}.pdf"'    
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, 
                    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]+ '/css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\static_root/css/pdf.css'

Comment: Is there `static_root` folder directly inside `Desktop`?

Comment: No, I don't know why it is searching there

Comment: What is the directory structure then??

Comment: I've added it in the post

Comment: What I mean is... here related to Desktop is `static_root`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223224/discussion-between-a-k-and-biplove-lamichhane).